# posting 2 values to array from single checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, multiple-value

I have a situation where I'd like to post two values to a search query string array from a single checkbox. Because of the design, I can't just add another checkbox.
The checkbox in question looks like so:

```
<input name="wpp_search[property_type][]" value="rental_home" type="checkbox" id="choice_c"/>
<label for="choice_c">For Rent</label>
```

what I now get in the query string is ...

```
{url}?wpp_search[property_type][0]=rental_home
```

but what I need is to tie two values to that one check so I end up with this:

```
{url}?wpp_search[property_type][0]=rental_home&wpp_search[property_type][1]=building
```

Any simple solutions? There is only one other checkbox that already feeds that array, so I could force this one to be

```
{url}?wpp_search[property_type][0]=rental_home&wpp_search[property_type][2]=building
```

Comment: A hidden input field, maybe? Or another parameter to the form you're submitting?

Comment: Do you have access to the actual PHP code that handles the form input?

Comment: @Pankucins I tried a hidden field, but seemed to have flubbed the conditional statement. I tried using if (isset($_POST['choice_c'])) then echo the hidden checkbox but it didn't post.

Comment: @Aaron W this is the actual line for the form: <form action="<?php echo  UD_F::base_url($wp_properties['configuration']['base_slug']); ?>" method='post'> but I haven't chased down where $wp_properties gets built originally. this is the submit: <button class="sendit" type="submit" name="submitbutton" title="Submit the form">Send it!</button> Obviously it's a WP site, and I don't even know what 'UD_F' does, I borrowed it form another search form. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it's not possible to send one value as two values.

One way I could imagine is that you reconfigure the ini-setting of [`arg_separator.input`](http://php.net/arg_separator.input):

```
arg_separator.input = ";&"
```

This will allow you to use `;` as well to separate values which then would allow you to inject the second value per that value:

```
<input name="wpp_search[property_type][0]" 
       value="rental_home;wpp_search[property_type][1]=building"
       ...
/>
```

If you make use of the value `;` in other form values you naturally need to properly escape them to make this compatible.

Another way is that you insert a hidden field with that value and if your checkbox is checked, you change the name of it to the right name. If unchecked, you change the name of it back to something not right:

```
<input type="hidden" name="---wpp_search[property_type][1]" value="=building" />
```

Take the javascript reference of your choice and do the needed DOM manipulation on click of the other checkbox to remove the three `---` at the beginning of the name.

Comment: thanks! I used the second idea with a jQuery swap and it worked great. In fact I realized I didn't need to assign the location, just left it wpp_search[property_type][] and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate values with for example "|" like this `value="value1|value2"`. Then later you can use the function explode: `$p = explode("|", $value);` and you get 2 values.